# Couldnt get records from mysql db

Tags: mysql, mariadb

The below query is not updating records in mysql.

```
update audit_login set used_by=null where used_by = "test1\suri";
```

select is also not fetching the records, but mysql workbench shows 2 records when queried on a different column.

When the following is run:

```
SELECT * FROM audit_login WHERE used_by like 'test%\suri`;
```

I get records back with `used_by` of `test1\suri`.

Please help

Comment: update audit_login set user=null where user = "test1\suri"; this is the actual query

Comment: By "not working" I assume you mean it doesn't change any of the rows?
 Or you get an error? If it's the latter, tell us the error. At a glance, mySQL normally expects strings to be in single quotes, not double quotes, so replace `"` with `'` and try again. Also. "select is not fetching records". There's no select query here. If your select isn't doing what you expect, I suggest you post it here so we can fix it.

Comment: select * from audit_login where used_by = 'test1\suri'; --> Returns no records

select used_by from audit_login where seq_no = '1234';--> Returns test1\suri

Comment: Do you have a record where `used_by` = `'test\suri'`? Is there any whitespace hanging out after that string in your record? If the `Update` doesn't update the rows and `Select` doesn't find them, then the data isn't what you think it is. Perhaps try: `SELECT * FROM audit_login WHERE used_by LIKE '%test\suri%';` If that returns records, then you have some whitespace in there that you aren't accounting for in your queries.

Comment: select * from audit_login where used_by like 'test%\suri'; is returning data but when i replace % with 1 no results found... actual value is 'test1\suri'

Comment: Use two backslashes maybe?

Comment: @Joop Eggen two backslashes worked thanks a ton....

Answer (score 2):

The backslash (\) is used as an escape character. To use a literal backslash, you must escape it:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM audit_login WHERE used_by = "test1\\suri";
+--------+------------+
| seq_no | used_by    |
+--------+------------+
|   1234 | test1\suri |
+--------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```